# Jetbrains Gateway settings for frequent disconnects

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-gateway

I’m using Jetbrains Gateway to use IntelliJ to work on the code in a remote Linux machine.
I connect via SSH. I connect and work fine initially, the latency is around 150 ms but it keeps disconnecting. I realized it disconnects when I stop coding and spend some time on other things (browser etc.). When I want to re-connect it asks for SSH key passphrase, I need to enter it multiple times and the 'Save Permanently' option won't work.

1. Is there a setting I can do to keep it connected?
2. Could this be related to my company's network, in which case again can I increase timeout or retry on fail by some settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using Remote Development feature of IntelliJ connecting to the same remote machine as described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-development-starting-page.html

[image]

It does not disconnect, I can work whole day (tested 12+ hours) without any connection issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is Max from the remote development team at JetBrains.
I'm sorry to hear you are having trouble with Gateway. Please create a ticket here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=GTW describing your issue and attaching your logs. This will help us understand whats going on and resolve your issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Please see my answer -- hopefully you can compare Gateway and builtin Intellij support for remote development and figure out the issue.